# Can I "daisy chain" powerline adaptors?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, powerline-networking

I have a farm, all on one power service (200A single phase mains) I'm trying to get better internet to my barn but there is more than 100M of wire from modem to barn. My extender works in the garage which is the location of the mains. (Modem is in the house, about 200 - 250 +/-' of wiring away) It doesn't reach to the barn, which is another 400- 500' of wire away. Can I place the extender there and patch a second system into that extender?

Comment: Probably not.   A Powerline extender needs to be on the same electric box as your device and this is not likely the case. You need to connect by fiber or have a second ISP. Long term, fiber will be cheaper. Even if on one box, I am not certain you can chain them together.

Comment: It is working thru multiple fuse boxes ATM, but the final jump seems a bridge too far. The main panel is in the garage (separate building) which feeds the house thru a disconnect then the house panel. The extender works fine through those, but doesn't reach the barn.

Comment: I would try the fiber connection as that will be much, much more reliable and even likely cheaper in the long run.

Comment: A fiber connection is not available. Fiber isn't available at all on our road. And adding an ISP or phone connection would require adding power poles etc. My question is if powerline adapter systems can be combined. I'm getting good service to my garage which is the jump off point for the wiring to the barn. If multiple systems will talk, the distance from garage to barn should be within limits...

Comment: Powerline performance would be impacted by all those fuses and those distances

Comment: Have you considered using a WIFI AP and AP client?   Paired with (an even slightly) directional antenna you should have no problem in a rural location if you have line of site.  I am almost certain I can do that with my old outdoor Ubiquity Omni aerial on one side paired with even a standard laptop over that distance on my lifestyle block (semi-rural property).  If you are using a Modem, chances are your Internet speed is not that high and WIFI will be able to max it out because you won't have a lot of interference.

Comment: Even if you were to achieve this somehow with powerline network, you're still left with the problem that powerline signal loss starts to kick in at around 300m. It has a max of 984 feet.. and Cat5e only has a max of 100m. You might want to consider a solution like this: https://www.fastcabling.com/pages/how-to-extend-the-cat5-network-up-to-500-meters/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, G.hn devices support multi-hop (mesh) relaying, but HomePlug devices do not. I've no experience with G.hn, but you're using the HomePlug standard I'm pretty sure this won't work.

---

You could ~probably~ make it work by configuring a *separate* HomePlug network for the barn right next to the main one (i.e. configuring a different HomePlug network ID via the software) and connecting them via short Ethernet patch cable, but I'm not sure if that'd be reliable (the two nearby plugs would probably interfere with each other).

```
House           Garage            Barn

 ,--Network 1-.        ,--Network 2-.
 |            |        |            |
HPAV#1 ~~~~~ HPAV#2~HPAV#3 ~~~~~ HPAV#4
               |      |
               `-Cat5-'
```

> A fiber connection is not available. Fiber isn't available at all on our road. And adding an ISP or phone connection would require adding power poles etc

I believe the suggestion was not to add an ISP or phone connection; it was to run *your own* fiber line from garage to barn. (Not the fancy GPON stuff that ISPs use, just basic fiber-Ethernet between two points.) The equipment and skill needed costs a bit more than copper Ethernet but it's still a realistic suggestion.

As yet another alternative, some companies sell PoE-powered copper Ethernet amplifiers that could be connected mid-way between your garage and barn.